# How to set VM for a Java application in MAC OS X

Tags: java, macos, virtual-machine

I am setting my VM for my Java application in Windows using a batch file with the following command:

```
java -jar -Xmx800m "App.jar"
```

Now I wanna do the same thing for MAC OS X? Any suggestions?

Comment: What problem do you face when doing this on Mac OSX?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same arguments for Java in Mac OS X.